# Exact differential equation,easiest way to approch

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}+y(1+x^2)=0$$
i found that this was exact and got
$$u= xy +\frac{x^3}{3}+c$$
as an answer
..But if we solve this using another method can the answer be changed..and what is the easiest way to solve a problem in this format.thanks.

Comment: **Hint:** Separation of Variables: $$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{y}~dy = \int -\dfrac{x^2+1}{x}~dx.$$ Also, are you sure your result is correct?

Comment: @Moo if we solve this by separation of variables and is it possible to get a difference answer than this

Comment: Test your answer, does it work?

Comment: What's $u$ in your answer? Given that your RHS is correct, answer should look like something similar to $xy + \frac {x^3}3 = c$ where $c$ is constant. Introducing a new function and considering its level set is unnecessary in my opinion. At least with the amount of information you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Separate variables:
$$ \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = -x-\frac{1}{x}. $$
Integrate:
$$ \log{y} = A-\frac{x^2}{2}-\log{x}. $$
Exponentiate:
$$ y = \frac{k}{x}e^{-x^2/2} $$
(where $k=e^A$). This is the only possible form the solution can take: if we take
$$ y= z\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x}, $$
then
$$ \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{z'}{z} - x - \frac{1}{x}, $$
so
$$ x\frac{dy}{dx} + y(1+x^2) = \frac{xy}{z}z', $$
and in order to satisfy the equation, we must have $z'=0$, so $z$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Put $z=xy $.

it becomes $$z'=-xz $$

it gives

$$\ln (\frac {z}{\lambda})=-\frac {x^2}{2} $$

and
$$z=\lambda.e^{-\frac {x^2}{2}}=xy $$